# ORA-30926: unable to get a stable set of rows in the source tables - MERGE

Tags: oracle

The below merge statement fails with this error 'ORA-30926: unable to get a stable set of rows in the source tables' . I tried to eliminate the duplicate from inner select query and the inner query gives no duplicates . But still I see the job failed with same error after rerun . Any help is appreciated.

My inner query is not giving any duplicates ... please clarify if I am missing something.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
                              col1,
                              col2,
                              col3,
                              col4,
                              col5,
                              col6,
                              col7,
                              col8
                         FROM table2
                        WHERE col7    IN (SELECT col1 FROM LOOKUP WHERE LEVEL_IND = 'L');





MERGE INTO TABLE1 UPLD
            USING (SELECT DISTINCT
                          col1,
                          col2,
                          col3,
                          col4,
                          col5,
                          col6,
                          col7,
                          col8
                     FROM table2
                    WHERE col7    IN (SELECT col1 FROM LOOKUP WHERE LEVEL_IND = 'L')) TMP_UPLD
               ON (    TMP_UPLD.col4      = UPLD.col4
                   AND TMP_UPLD.col5 = UPLD.col5)
       WHEN MATCHED
       THEN
           UPDATE SET
               UPLD.COL7    = TMP_UPLD.col1,
               UPLD.col3 = TMP_UPLD.col3,
               UPLD.col2             = TMP_UPLD.col2
         WHERE TRAN_PERIOD              = pi_tran_period
               AND TRAN_YEAR            = pi_tran_year
               AND TRAN_BATCH           = pi_tran_batch
               AND SOURCE_INSTANCE      = ps_source_instance
               AND d_flag    = 'D'
               AND A_FLAG     IS NULL
               AND COL7         = TMP_UPLD.COL7 
               AND UPLD.A_DATE = TMP_UPLD.ACT_DATE
               AND UPLD.SEQUENCE_NUMBER > TMP_UPLD.ACT_SEQUENCE_NUMBER
               AND col7        IN (SELECT col1 FROM LOOKUP WHERE LEVEL_IND = 'L');
```

Comment: There are no duplicates from SELECT DISTINCT
                          col1,
                          col2,
                          col3,
                          col4,
                          col5,
                          col6,
                          col7,
                          col8
                     FROM table2
                    WHERE col7    IN (SELECT col1 FROM LOOKUP WHERE LEVEL_IND = 'L')) TMP_UPLD

Comment: Its not duplicate problem ...not sure why put as duplicate issue

Comment: are you sure? then have a look at my example: *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=682549158ac098c8c8f6cea4f295fc2c)*

Comment: even though I eliminated duplicates from that distinct query based matching joining conditions with other tables will bring duplicates ?